# valid proof of series $\sum \limits_{v=1}^n v$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

$$\sum \limits_{v=1}^n v=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$

please don't downvote if this proof is stupid, it is my first proof, and i am only in grade 5, so i haven't a teacher for any of this 'big sums'

proof:

if we look at $\sum \limits_{v=1}^3 v=1+2+3,\sum \limits_{v=1}^4 v=1+2+3+4,\sum \limits_{v=1}^5 v=1+2+3+4+5$

i learnt rainbow numbers in class three years ago, so i use that knowlege here:

$n=3,1+3=4$ and $2$.

$n=4,1+4$ and $2+3$

$n=5,1+5$ and $2+4$ and $3$

and more that i have done on paper that i don't wanna type.

we can see from this for the odd case that we have $(n+1)$ added together moving in from the outside, so we get to add $(n+1)$ to the total $\frac{(n-1)}2$ times plus the center number, which is $\frac{n+1}2$.. giving $\frac{n-1}2(n+1)+\frac{n+1}2=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{2}+\frac{n+1}{2}$ and i can get $\frac{n^2-1}2+\frac{n+1}2=\frac{n^2+n}2$ which is what we want.

so odd are proven.

for even we have a simplier problem: we have $n+1$ on each pair of numbers going in. since we are even numbers, we have $1+n=n+1$ , with $n$ even, $2+(n-1)=n+1$ and we can see this is good for all numbers since we increase one side by one and lower the other by 1. so we get $\frac{n}2$ times $n+1$ gives $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$

thus is proven for all cases. thus is is proven

Comment: Your proof is really elementary and very nice in my opinion. Btw: This formula is related to Gauss, who redeveloped it at school at the age of 9 years. And now comes the clue: He used exactly the same idea as you did :) However, the proofs by induction or the proof mentioned in the answer below (which used the same idea, too!) is more pure and elegant.

Comment: @sranthrop oh that is really cool! thank you for you're comfirmation! he beat me by 2 years hehe!

Comment: The terms of service for this website say you have to be 13 to use it, so, unless you have been left back several times....

Comment: @GerryMyerson don't please, i just want to learn math please!

Comment: @GerryMyerson can you delete that??

Comment: You should take a look at this page. It explains the idea of mathematical induction pretty cleanly, in my opinion, and will illustrate exactly what you want to show.http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/mathematical-induction.html

Also, good on you for being both able and willing to tackle proofs. I know a lot of people in my classes as an upper classman at university that are still afraid of proof after many years of working with them. Keep doing what you're doing, it's definitely admirable!

Comment: @AlfredYerger thank you so much alfred for the website and the motivation! i will read it and see if i can get it!

Comment: Also take a look at http://mathuprising.comlu.com/sum-squares.html. Outlines a geometric strategy for solving the "stacking apples" problem.

Comment: Very natural, intuitive proof, I like it. I used a similar technique to prove it. Once you get to calculus, you will see there is a way using integrals and polynomial interpolation to prove the sum of any polynomial. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While most of the proofs that you will see are algebraic, sometimes it is useful to get a geometric view of the problem. I've always preferred getting multiple perspectives to give me deeper understanding of the problem at hand.

In the image, there are 5 different views of the problem. The first one has $(n+1)^2 - (n+1)$ cookies arranged in a square, with the diagonal removed. The second one arranges $n^2$ pizza into a square and then cuts the square in half. The third view arranges two sets of cookies into triangles to form a single rectangle. The fourth view we arrange squares into $n$ Ls that fit together to form a rectangle. Lastly, we have $n+1$ computers on a network that connects every computer directly to every other computer.  [image]

As an exercise, try cutting the middle row of pizzas in half horizontally, and rearrange the triangle of pizzas into a rectangle.

[image]

Comment: a user kaj hansen from chat told me about ramsey numbers and i learnt some graph theory which is fun. but i still cant solve the computer one, it is $K_6$, so has $5*6$ degree, so degree $30$ so $15$ edges, so then we have $15$ connections? which i see is at $\sum \limits_{v=1}^5 v=15$

if i make it 7 computers i get $7*6=42$ degree total and then i get $21$ total edges, so that mean i have $\sum \limits_{v=1}^6 v=21$

so that mean that $n+1$ computers solves for the $n$ series, i think that is it

Comment: oh i see i see, that is really cool! i get the computers and they all have degree 1 less so that means i have $n(n+1)$ degree, and we have 2 degree for each edges, so we get $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ thank you!

Comment: I wasn't familiar with Ramsey numbers until you mentioned them, but I think that you may be over-thinking the problem. The number of ways to fully connect a network of $n+1$ computers is the same as the number of ways to choose $2$ computers from a set of $n+1$ computers (i.e. $\binom{n+1}{2}$ or $\frac{(n+1)n}{1\cdot2}$).

Comment: thank you for all the example ways to think! i enjoyed them all!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with "rainbow numbers", and I'm afraid I can't follow every step of your proof. But if you're just looking for a very elementary proof of this, here's the easiest one I can think of:

Write the sum forwards:

$S_n = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n$

and then backwards:

$S_n = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1$

and then sum term by term to get:

$2S_n = (n+1) + (n+1) +... + (n+1)$

where there are exactly $n$ of those terms.

So $2S_n = n(n+1)$

and $S_n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$.

My apologies if this doesn't answer your question. I just thought you might want a nice elementary method to approach this (and it looks like less work than splitting into cases, etc.)

Comment: oh wow that is so cool!!!!! i cant believe it!!!

Comment: rainbow numbers adds the first and last number together, and then the 2nd and 2nd last so on.

so $1+2+3+4=(1+4)+(2+3)=5+5=10$

$1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=(1+8)+(2+7)+(3+6)+(4+5)=9+9+9+9=36$

Comment: thank you for that really cool way to solve it!

Comment: Looks to me like the rainbow numbers are doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: @beginner You're welcome. If "rainbow numbers" involve adding the 1st and last, 2nd and 2nd last,... etc., then it's pretty much the same thing as Alfred points out. The only issue with that method is that you have to consider the odd and even cases separately. Not at all difficult, but the method I presented is even simpler and more hassle-free. :)

Comment: This is an awesome website to familiarize yourself with rainbow numbers  http://www.google.com

Comment: @JohnJoy By just linking to the main search site without providing a specific link, I can't help but think you're being more than a little sarcastic. If so, good job (see, two can play at that). In any case, a google search revealed no authoritative sources for the term "rainbow numbers". By authoritative, I mean a website such as mathworld.wolfram.com It sounds to me like "rainbow numbers" is a term peculiar to junior US (or North American) math education. If so, one should not reasonably expect those outside of this system (rather a lot of us!) to be familiar with such "colloquialisms".

Comment: oh it is the same true, but this is neater by far! i didn't know you could do the multi 'big sum' thingm so that was nice to see. thanks again :)

Comment: @Deepak Thank you for picking up on my sarcasm. We don't just stop learning when we finish school. If there is some topic that one is "not familiar with", then obviously one can take action to familiarize oneself with said topic. Admittedly though, searching for "rainbow numbers" may be less successful then searching for "rainbow facts". They are used to teach early  elementary students (e.g. grade 2) addition facts (see this non-US site http://www.teachthis.com.au/products/view-resource/link/Rainbow-Facts/id/119). By the way, I was unfamiliar with rainbow numbers too until OP mentioned them.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\sum_{v=1}^nv=\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{v=1}^n2v=\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{v=1}^n\left((v+1)^2-v^2-1\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left((n+1)^2-(n+1)\right)-=\dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)$

Comment: is that true that you can take the number out the front of the 'big sum'?

Comment: wait ill prove it!

Comment: @beginner: You mean the $\dfrac{1}{2}$?

Comment: yes ill prove it though, that you can take them out, it does seem right because you cahnge all terms evenly

Comment: Never thought to use the difference of perfect squares. Love this solution! :)